# DART/FLUTTER - To empty a list : What is the real difference between myList.clear() and myList=[ ]?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

In the following code : I use a temporary list (pp2) to complete the parameter "smartLearningProgression" of an object I called VocList. I have a list called "_carnetListUser1" which is a list of VocLists.
pp2 is initialised  (pp2=[]) earlier in the code.

At one moment of the algorythm I need to empty my temporary list (pp2). When I use pp2.clear(); it doesn't work at all : "smartLearningProgression" is always empty as if pp2 never keeps its value, when I use pp2 =[], it works fine.

I just don't understand why !! :) Anyone has an idea why ??

Here is the code :

```
  final _fireStoreVocListUser1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('familyAccounts')
          .doc(id)
          .collection('users')
          .doc('user1')
          .collection('vocList');
      await _fireStoreVocListUser1.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          ppTemp = doc['smartLearningProgression'].toList();
          pp2 = []; // if I replace this by pp2.clear(); it doesn't work...
           
          for (Map pp in ppTemp) {
            pp2.add(PartProgress(
              step1: pp['step1'],
              step2: pp['step2'],
              step3: pp['step3'],
              step4: pp['step4'],
              checkPoint: pp['checkPoint'],
            ));
           
          }
          
          _carnetListUser1.add(VocList(
              ref: doc['ref'],
              titre: doc['titre'],
              creation: doc['dateCreation'].toDate(),
              modification: doc['dateModification'].toDate(),
              firstSession: doc['firstSession'].toDate(),
              latestSession: doc['latestSession'].toDate(),
              listMastery: doc['listMastery'].toDouble(),
              test: doc['test'],
              testDate: doc['testDate'].toDate(),
              carnetWordId: doc['carnetWordId'],
              smartLearningList: doc['smartLearningList'],
              smartLearningProgression: pp2,
              mastery: []));
        });
      });
```

Comment: ```pp2 = [] ``` this will create a new reference to an empty array which means a new memory slot, calling ```.clear()``` will keep the same reference to the array which means one array shared between all your instances, doing a clear from one instance will clear the data from all the others because in reality it is only one array. it makes sense ?

Comment: Yes I get what you are saying, but I still don't see why if I write "pp2.clear()" in my code : for some reason, smartLearningProgression doesn't keep its value... or maybe I just got it... shoudln't I write for smartLearningProgression : list.of(pp2) ?

Comment: Yep this works : in fact when I wrote "smartLearningProgression : pp2", it didn't really affect the values of pp2 to smartLearningProgression : it "linked" both lists together... so indeed, when I cleared pp2, it cleared all of them... so since I just wanted the values of pp2 affected to smartLearningProgession, I had to use the List.of function :)

Comment: yes it is correct, or you can do ```[...p2]``` (three dots) , I can share it as an answer if you think it is useful ?

Comment: Can you explain this syntax to me ? [...p2], I never get the "dots" syntax...    Yes you can share it, it was clearly useful :) It set me on the right track :)

Comment: This called Array/Object spread operator, it is useful when you need to create new reference of an array ```[...array]``` or merge two arrays ```[...array1,...array2]```, it is also used by an object for example you have one object and you need to create new one but with another name, you can do ```object2 = {...object1, name:"new name"}. you can search on the name of it for more deeper info and usecases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem, let me first describe the problem and then the solution.
`pp2 = []` will create a new reference to an empty array which means a new memory slot.

Calling `.clear()` will just clear the data from the array being called from (pp2 in this case), this means there is no change in the reference, then this one array is shared between all your instances, doing a clear from one instance will clear the data from all the others because in reality it is only one array (one reference).

To solve this you need to create new array reference for each new instance, you have many ways for this :

1. `var newList = List.of(pp2)`
2. `var newList = [...pp2]` *Array/Object spread operator*
3. `var newList = []`

To give an example :

```
  var array1 = [5,6,7];
  var array2= array1;
  
  array2[0] = 20;

  print(array1); // [20, 6, 7]
  print(array2); // [20, 6, 7]
```

Changing `array2` affected `array` because they have the same reference.