# Getting duplicate documents while fetching documents from firebase in flutter using providers

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

i am trying to fetch all the documents in a certain collection in firebase and add it to a list to view it as listview , but it runs again and again and i get duplicate infinite entries of the same documents in list

This is the code in the screen where I want to show the listview

```
body: Center(
        child: Consumer<ClassProvider>(
          builder: (context,classProvider , _){
            final classList = classProvider.classes;
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),

              child: classList.isEmpty
                  ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
                  : GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: classList.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 2.0,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: ((context, i) => InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: Colors.teal),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          classList[i].name,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Records.routeName,arguments: classList[i].name);
                    },
                  ))),
            );
          },
```

Below is the provider file

```
class ClassProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final CollectionReference classList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      "classes"); //this is the collection reference to classes collection

  final List<Class> _classes = [
    // Class(name: "3CE12", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE34", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE56", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE78", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
  ];

  final List<String> _recordList = [
    // Class(name: "3CE12", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE34", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE56", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
    // Class(name: "3CE78", subject: "ML", instructor: "Navdeep"),
  ];
  final List<Student> _studentList = [
    //this list will store the students

  ];



  //method to get the list of classes from firebase
  Future getClassesList() async {
    await classList.get().then((querySnapshot) {
      //querySnapshot is the list of all the documents in classes collection
      for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
        _classes.add(Class(
            name: element.get("className"),
            subject: element.get("subject"),
            instructor: element.get("instructor")));
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Class> get classes {     // getter function
    getClassesList(); //calling the classes function
    return [..._classes];  // ... is used because the copy of that data is stored in classes variable
  }

  List<String> get recordList {     // getter function
    //getClassesList(); //calling the classes function
    return [..._recordList];  // ... is used because the copy of that data is stored in classes variable
  }

  List<Student> get studentList{
    return [..._studentList];
  }

  Class findById(String className) {
    return _classes.firstWhere((element) => element.name == className);
  }
  //below is the code to fetch the previous records from firebase

   Future getRecordList(String className)  async {
     _recordList.clear();
     final CollectionReference currentRecordList = classList.doc(className)
         .collection('record');
     await currentRecordList.get().then((querySnapshot) {
       for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
         _recordList.add(element.id);
       }
     });
     notifyListeners();
   }


    //below is the code to fetch all the student roll numbers in a class
   Future getStudentList(String className, String recordDate) async{
    _studentList.clear();
    final  currentRecordDate = classList.doc(className).collection('record').doc(recordDate);//this currentRecordDate stores the id of document we are trying to access
    final data = await currentRecordDate.get();
    Map<String, dynamic> values = data.data() as Map<String, bool>;//this map contains all the values
     values.forEach((key, value) {
       _studentList.add(Student(name: key, isPresent: values[key]));
     });
     notifyListeners();

   }

}
```

Below is the Class Model

```
class Class {
  final String name;
  final String subject;
  final String instructor;

  Class({
    required this.name,
    required this.subject,
    required this.instructor,
  });
}
class Student{
  final String name;
  final bool isPresent;

  Student({
   required this.name,
   required this.isPresent
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to clear list. You can know more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68682901/13973724)

```
 _studentList = [];
_recordList=[];
```